# How can I assert lists equality with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to make some unit tests with ***pytest***.

I was thinking about doing things like that:

```
actual = b_manager.get_b(complete_set)
assert actual is not None
assert actual.columns == ['bl', 'direction', 'day']
```

The first assertion in ok but with the second I have an value error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I assume it is not the right way to assert the equality of two different lists with pytest.

How can I assert that the dataframe columns (a list) is equal to the expected one?

Thanks

Comment: The traceback includes a hint... Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`. BTW `assert` is not the 'normal' way to do unittesting

Comment: @Chris_Rands `assert` is **THE** way to test values under `pytest`. `pytest` internally rewrites byte code of `assert`s and calls its own comparison function.

Comment: Is `actual.columns` a list? The traceback suggests it's a bool.

Comment: actual.columns is a list indeed. After a little bit of investigations I realized that the comparison returns another list with booleans to check if the content is different or not. [True, False, True, True ..].And that's why I have to use the .All().. To be able to give to the Assert a unique Boolean not a list of booleans

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm using pytest, not the builtin unittest framework. Then what should be a normal way to do unittest?

Comment: I think this is best answered in this older question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946306/11715259

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could do a list comprehension to check equality of all values. If you call `all` on the list comprehensions result, it will return `True` if all parameters are equal.

```
actual = ['bl', 'direction', 'day']
expected = ['bl', 'direction', 'day']

assert len(actual) == len(expected)
assert all([a == b for a, b in zip(actual, expected)])

print(all([a == b for a, b in zip(actual, expected)]))

>>> True
```

Comment: @smerlung all() takes an iterable, the list comparison would return a bool.

Comment: You've forgot about list length check. zip() function cut output by list with minimal size.

rewrite actual and set it to ['bl', 'direction', 'day', 'MYAHAHA'] or even [] and get True too :P

I'll try to rewrite your sample.

Answer (score 114):

See [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#our-first-test-run):

> Note:
>
> You can simply use the `assert` statement for asserting test
>   expectations. pytest’s [Advanced assertion introspection](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assert-introspection) will
>   intelligently report intermediate values of the assert expression
>   freeing you from the need to learn the many names of [JUnit legacy
>   methods](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#test-cases).

And [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#making-use-of-context-sensitive-comparisons):

> Special comparisons are done for a number of cases:
>
> - comparing long strings: a context diff is shown
> - comparing long sequences: first failing indices
> - comparing dicts: different entries

And the [reporting demo](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/reportingdemo.html):

```
failure_demo.py:59: AssertionError
_______ TestSpecialisedExplanations.test_eq_list ________

self = <failure_demo.TestSpecialisedExplanations object at 0xdeadbeef>

    def test_eq_list(self):
>       assert [0, 1, 2] == [0, 1, 3]
E       assert [0, 1, 2] == [0, 1, 3]
E         At index 2 diff: 2 != 3
E         Use -v to get the full diff
```

See the assertion for lists equality with literal `==` over there? pytest has done the hard work for you.

Comment: Good answer. Should be the accepted. Please bring actual code samples to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting the error message of `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` even though I'm using pytest version 4.3.0

Comment: @AllenWang it is likely that one or both of your values for comparison are numpy arrays.  It seems in that case pytest would test for the truth value of numpy array resulting from the comparison, which is a numpy array of boolean values, and numpy would yield the above warning.  Try wrapping both values with `list()`.

Answer (score 43):

There are two keys to answer this seemingly simple answer:
conditions of equality and assertion error helpfulness.

The conditions of equality depend on given constrains and requirements.
Assertion error should point to the violation of those conditions.

Answer the following questions:

1. Is order of lists important?

   > are `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` equal?
2. Can lists have duplicates?

   > are `[1, 2]` and `[1, 1, 2]` equal?
3. Are there unhashable elements?

   > are there any mutable types?
4. Should assertion error be informative and helpful?

### No, No, No, No: symmetric difference between sets

```py
def test_nnnn():
    expected = [1, 2, 3]
    actual = [4, 3, 2, 1]
    difference = set(a) ^ set(b)
    assert not difference
```

`E       assert not {4, 5}`

It is handy to use this method on large lists, because it's fast and  `difference` will contain only hm difference between them, so `AssertionError` will be compact, however not informative.

### No, No, No, Yes:  difference between sets with custom message

```py
def test_nnny():
    expected = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    actual = [5, 3, 2, 1]
    lacks = set(expected) - set(actual)
    extra = set(actual) - set(expected)
    message = f"Lacks elements {lacks} " if lacks else ''
    message += f"Extra elements {extra}" if extra else ''
    assert not message
```

`E       AssertionError: assert not 'Lacks elements {4} Extra elements {5}'`

### No, Yes, No, Yes: check for duplicates, than difference in sets

Because `set()` removes duplicates you should check for them ahead [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835819/11056254):

```py
def test_nyny():
    expected = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    actual = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]

    seen = set()
    duplicates = list()
    for x in actual:
        if x in seen:
            duplicates.append(x)
        else:
            seen.add(x)

    lacks = set(expected) - set(actual)
    extra = set(actual) - set(expected)
    message = f"Lacks elements {lacks} " if lacks else ''
    message += f"Extra elements {extra} " if extra else ''
    message += f"Duplicate elements {duplicates}" if duplicates else ''
    assert not message
```

`E       AssertionError: assert not 'Lacks elements {4} Extra elements {5} Duplicate elements [3]'`

### Yes, Yes, Yes, No: compare lists

```py
def test_yyyn():
    expected = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, {'a': 1}]
    actual = [3, 3, 2, 1, {'a': 1}]
    assert expected == actual
```

`E       AssertionError: assert [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, {'a': 1}] == [3, 3, 2, 1, {'a': 1}]`

### Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes: extra libraries

Take a look at [DeepDiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/)

Comment: This doesn't work for cases like `a = [1,1,2] and b = [1, 2, 2]`

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is up to you to decide what parameters of lists to take into comparison.

Comment: `sorted([1, {'a': 1}, 2, 3])` → "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'". `sorted([{'a': 2}, {'a': 1}])` → "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'".

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @l0b0: for sorted you could use `sorted(..., key=id)`

Comment: For the 1) No, 2) Yes, 3) N/A situation, better see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946306/11715259

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the built in `unittest.TestCase`, there is already a method that can do that for you: `unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual` if you care about the list ordering, and `unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual` if you don't.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual

Comment: I'm using pytest, not the builtin unittest package. That's why I'm not using assertListEqual..

Comment: Calling `unittest.TestCase().assertCountEqual(first, second)` in a pytest testcase works just fine. You will get somewhat worse error message (with traceback from within the assertCountEqual method) if the assert fails, but otherwise there is no problem with that.

Comment: This is the best answer for the general case with unmeaningful order, potential duplicates, potentially unsortable data records, potentially different but comparable but unsortable data types. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946306/11715259

Answer (score 13):

In Python 3.9, this should now work:

```py
def test_arrays_equal():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [1, 2, 4]
    assert a == b
```

Or, you can parse the lists to `numpy` arrays and use function `array_equal`:

```
import numpy as np

def test_arrays_equal():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [1, 2, 4]
    ar = np.array(a)
    br = np.array(b)
    assert np.array_equal(ar, br)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the numpy arrays to python lists and you'll get a better response than simply using `all` or `any`. This way, if the test fails you'll see how the expected vs actual differ

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://github.com/AdityaSavara/UnitTesterSG which can be obtained by pip UnitTesterSG